# Hide state structure in production

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using Provider from react-redux. In production, I can see the state structure if I have the react chrome extension installed using `$r.store.getState()`. How do I hide this behavior in production ?

Comment: Why do you want to hide the state? What's the harm in a user being able to see their data?

Answer (score 3):

You can make global `$r` variable **not** writable, using `Object.defineProperty` function:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, '$r', {
  writable: false
});
```

In that case, React Devtools can't assign a value to `$r` variable and therefore no one can access store instance using React Devtools.

**Edit:**

When setting `writable: false` property, React Devtools throws an error, that `$r` property is not writable. In order to avoid that error, you can set constant value to that variable that way:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, '$r', {
  value: {}
});
```

In that case, `$r` value will be always equal to `{}` and console will be silent.